# Apache Camel does not retain file in source folder

Tags: java, apache-camel

While working on Apache Camel, whenever a file is zipped using camel-zip or copied via canel-ftp,  Camel moves the file in **.Camel** folder and does not retain it in source folder after processing.
I want my file to stay in the source folder after the processing has been done. 
Please advice how to achieve the same.

CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {

```
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {

            from("file:src/main/zip?delete=false").marshal().zipFile()
                    .to("file:C:/Users/kdewan/Desktop");
        }

    });
    context.start();
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    context.stop();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please Check the **"noop"** property in Camel-File component.
 By default it is **"false"** so it will move the processed folder in to .camel .
 If you dont want to move it in .camel folder make it **"noop" property "true"**.

Answer (score 5):

Camel moves files into the *.Camel* directory to avoid multiple processing of the same file.
Ftp component inherits all options from [file component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html), therefore it is possible to set a different location as archive directory:

```
ftp:...&move=directory/archive&moveFailed=directory/error
```

*move*: is the archive directory where the processed files should be stored

*moveFailed*: is the directory when an error occurred during processing

I believe the same logic can be used for camel-zip too.

When I use file component, I create this structure on my file system for better monitoring:

```
-- basic/Directory
---- /working
---- /archive
---- /error
```